# Tool for collaborative c++ API design

Tags: software-development, api

I am looking for a tool which allows a (small) team to develop, discuss and document a C/ C++ API together. So far all the tools I found are target REST / WEB APIs.

Ideally the tool whould also allow to trace requirements for the API as well.

There is some budget for this, if there is some opensource tool we can use this would be a bonus.

Comment: What OS must it run on? Is there any budget, or must the software be available for free?

Comment: OS is not important (windows , linux ). updated the question with info about the budget

Comment: You can use any collaberative coding enviroment, plus DoxyGen